# Union two objects, but omit falsy values

Tags: javascript

How can I union two objects, but omit to merge falsy values like `0, "", false`, from the second object?

I want it to work in both ways and doesn't depend on the order i pass the objects

So this example is not an options: `const union = {...obj2, ...obj1};`

```js
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: { c1: 12, c2: 15 }};
const obj2 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: { c1: 0, c2: 0 }, d: 3};

const union = {...obj1, ...obj2};
console.log(union);
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": {
    "c1": 12,
    "c2": 15
  },
  "d": 3
}
```

Comment: `const union = {...obj2, ...obj1};`

Comment: i want it to work in both ways and doesn't depend on order i pass objects. Sorry i needed to specify this in my post

Comment: If you "*want it to work in both ways [not depending] on order [you] pass objects*", you're implying that there truly is no concept of a "*second object*" (per your question). The way I interpret it, these statements are not compatible with one another and your constraints here cannot possibly be satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recursive funtion to merge nested objects with a condition.

```js
function union(a, b) {
    return [a, b].reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (!v) return;
            r[k] = typeof v === 'object'
                ? union(r[k] || {}, v)
                : v;
        })
        return r;
    }, {});
}

console.log(union(
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: { c1: 12, c2: 15 } },
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: { c1: 0, c2: 0 }, d: 3 }

));
```